# specific function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, gravity

I have a function took on a tutorial, it works fine with one only element but I want to use it with some elements and I do not know enough about Javascript to do so.

This is my function :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('boules');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  gameAccel(elements[i]);
}

function gameAccel(sphere) {
   var x=20,y=300,vx=0,vy=0,ax=0,ay=0;
   if(window.DeviceMotionEvent!=undefined){
       window.ondevicemotion=function(e){
           ax=event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x*3;
           ay=event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y*3;
       }
       monInterval = setInterval(function(){
          var landscapeOrientation=window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight>1;
          if(landscapeOrientation){
              vx=vx+ay;
              vy=vy+ax;
          }else{
              vy=vy-ay;
              vx=vx+ax;
          }
          vx=vx*0.98;
          vy=vy*0.98;
          y=parseInt(y+vy/50);
          x=parseInt(x+vx/50);
          boundingBoxCheck();
          sphere.style.top=y+"px";
          sphere.style.left=x+"px";                                   
       },25);
   }
   function boundingBoxCheck(){
      if(x<0){x=0;vx=-vx;}
      if(y<0){y=0;vy=-vy;}
      if(x>document.documentElement.clientWidth-40){
            x=document.documentElement.clientWidth-40;
            vx=-vx;
      }
      if(y>document.documentElement.clientHeight-40){
            y=document.documentElement.clientHeight-40;
            vy=-vy;
      }
   }
}
```

I have one element with "boules" class, it works, if I have several elements with "boules" class it doesn't works.

This function is used on mobile device with gyroscope. (this is the basic example http://www.albertosarullo.com/demos/accelerometer/).

Someone can explain me why and how I can correct that ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it expected that all `.boules` will have the same position? If so, then just use a loop over `elements` where you are assigning the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `window.ondevicemotion` and `monInterval` every time you call the function. Only the last handler will be triggered. Instead, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to attach multiple handlers and a [local variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: hm ok I understand overwriting. Can you give me an example to resolve problem with addEventListener ?

Comment: Simply use that method instead of assigning to the `ondevicemotion` property.

Comment: I have change this part :

window.addEventListener("devicemotion",onDeviceMotion,false);
function onDeviceMotion(event){                                          ax=event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x*3;ay=event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y*3;
}

It's ok ?

And for Interval I don't know what I need to do.

Comment: Looks good. For `monInterval` just add a `var ` before it, however you don't seem to use that variable anyway.

Comment: Oh it's works, thanks, it was missing not many thing, good for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You have overwrites `window.ondevicemotion` handler in every loop. It must works only for last handler.